# Text to Columns with a return seperation

Tags: excel

I have a cell in Excel with 6 or so names in them, formatted as lastname,firstname, [line break]
lastname,firstname, [line break]
etc.

I need to be able to get these names into outlook as contacts, which only recognizes lastname,firstname; lastname,firstname; etc.

Is there a way to use text to columns to break out these names based upon the line break? Or is there some other way you can recommend to get the names email ready?

Comment: Break the names apart on the ","s then put them back together putting ";" where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question, but there is a way, but it's kind of a lot of work.

1. Click on the cells (columns) you want to split apart and format.
2. Click on Data → Text to Columns
3. Make sure "Delimited" is selected.
4. In the Wizard, click "Next"
5. Click the "Space" checkbox
6. Click "Next"
7. Click "Finish"
8. Click on a cell of any empty column.
9. Type: =(
10. Click on the first cell with the Lastname,Firstname
11. Type: &";"&
12. Click on the next cell with Lastname,Firstname
13. Type: &";"&
14. Repeat steps 11 and 12 until you've finished
15. Type: )
16. Hit "Enter"

You should have your names formatted as:

```
Lastname,Firstname;Lastname,Firstname
```

It's a lot of work, but it does what you requested.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply. My issue with that is that the carriage returns don't work with the text to columns, so it would only search the first name. I just figured out a way to do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You can do a find and replace on the carriage return using control+J as what you're searching for, and ";" to replace it. Then do another find and replace on ", " and replace with "". It then added ; to each carriage return, and deleted the extra comma.

Comment: Select this as the answer to close the question. :)